# /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd constantly crashes

Tags: mount, udisks

I am constantly getting an internal error message from Ubuntu:

> Sorry, Ubuntu 17.10 has experienced an internal error.
>   ExecutablePath: /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd

The only disk I have in the system is SAMSUNG 960 EVO MZ-V6E500BW

Is there a way to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: I experience the same problem  in 17.10. No solution at hand.

Comment: @opinion_no9 Has it occured in earlier versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: Hallo Denis, no, it never appeared before under 16.n. Unfortunately this is a server machine, not supposed to run under 17. Due to problems with the 4T GPT disc I upgraded to 17.10 - a big mistake. Many crashes of OS and applications. Try to survive w/o going back to 16.n.  The udisksd crash led to some (hopefully minor) errors in the smb- and nfs  mounted file system for the users. The HW is quite fresh, Ryzen3, no M2 disc.
Help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 5):

This is in the ubuntu bug tracker with no work-around as yet (2018.Mar.27) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/+bug/1707451

I'd rather have made this a comment but I'm not allowed yet!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this bug has been fixed as of 2018-04-06. Builds can be downloaded at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/2.7.6-3

Comment: I'm still getting this on 18.04.1. Even after fresh installs.

Comment: I got this on 19.04 shame on you Samsung :(